# What determines order of execution of 'set' in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, angular

I have the following code:

```
....
set whatEver(){
}

set whatEver2(){
}
```

and I load my Component in the following way:

```
@Component({
...
properties: [
'whatEver:whatEver',
'whatEver2:whatEver2'
]
})
```

I am wondering what exactly orders the order of execution of the set? In my more developed app, whatever2 gets called before whatever.

In my DOM, the order is as the following:

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would assume it's the order in the DOM not in the component definition.

```
<what-ever [whatEver]="foo" [whatEver2]="bar">
```

Comment: Actually, I am just checked that. It has the opposite order in the DOM. However, when I chagne the order, it doesnt change the order of execution.

Comment: Then it's either a bug or Angular2 won't guarantee any order and it is as it is. You might create a bug report to get a definitive answer.

Comment: Actually it shouldn't matter. If you have code that depends on the order than I'd suggest you move it to `ngOnInit()` where both are guaranteed to be set (if provided).